# Taxonomize the right way 

Tags: drupal, taxonomy, project-organization

I'm facing an organizational problem and thought maybe someone could enlighten me :)
I'm working on a classifieds website using drupal and i just can't figure out how to seperate the posts published for each place.

Imagine the website can be used by people from three cities. Chicago, Boston, Seattle
The cities have the same sections : Cars, Furniture, Computers.

What i want is to let the visitor choose his city first, from a select list for example. That will take him to : his_city.website.com
Then he can either browse by sections and sub-sections or either create a new post

I tried adding the cities as sections and then adding categories and sub-category but it doesn't feel right
When creating a new post, all the cities and their categories/sub-categories appear and it can be really confusing for people.

I went to see how they do on Craigslist and it's pretty much what i have in mind.

`http://city.language.website.com/main-section/category/sub-category`

How would you taxonomize this ?

I thought maybe different drupal installations ( one for each city ) but is it possible to connect the databases to allow users to sign up without having to create multiple accounts on each city .. ?

Anyway, any ideas are welcome

Thank you very much

p.s : Switching the website's language while keeping the same content is the big next question i'll be dealing with :)

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 taxonomy vaocabularies 
One for cites
One for categories

Creating node user should determinate 2 vocabularies

To use city taxonomy voc for domain use [Domain Taxonomy](http://drupal.org/node/256763)

Comment: +1, but all the methods here would work! Using a node-reference could be handy if you want to provide some extra information on the locations as well. Using the domain module is a must if you want to be working on localization.

Comment: >> Using the domain module is a must if you want to be working on localization <<< or have single BO.

Comment: i didn't know about the Domain Access module but it seems to fit exactly with what i'm trying to do.  Dumb question : What do you mean by a "single BO" ?  Thanks !!

Comment: single back office. Admin will see content of all 3 domains in the admin part.

Answer (score 0):

For cities: Domain module
For taxonomy modules: views + path + pathauto.

Comment: Yes i think that's the way i'll be doing it.  Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Its not currently possibly to reliably limit taxonomy fields in this way. The other solution is to make those cities nodes, then allow users to create new items using a pre-populated nodereference field.